SQL Server conditional join on column value
I have two tables - Table A and Table B
Table A
Value      Value2      Number
-------    ------      ------
AA          1          138
AB          2          234
AC          3          897
BA          4          274
BB          5          391
CA          4          994
CA          5          287

Table B
Value      Value2      Number
-------    ------      ------
AA          1          458
AB          2          434
AC          3          557
CA          4          564

I am joining Table A and Table B with respect to Value and Value2 column.
SELECT
     * 
FROM
   Table A TA 
JOIN
   Table B TB ON 
   TA.Value = TB.Value 
   AND TA.Value2 = TB.Value2

Table A and Table B does not have all the matching value, for example value column of Table A have BA and BB which is not matching in Table B value column, so I need to replace BA and BB with CA and join it.
I started writing the script but wrote a long script.
I used except to get all the value column from TABLE A not matching TABLE B , and put this into a temp table. Then loop and replace the BA / BB column with CA column. But I think there should be a easy steps than this which I struggle to find.
Any suggestions please.

Please add the expected result

And what if CA doesn't exist? Move onto DA? We need those desired results and they need to cover all the edge cases.

See example
create table table_A(Value varchar(2), Value2 int, Number int);
insert into table_A values
 ('AA',          1,          138)
,('AB',          2,          234)
,('AC',          3,          897)
,('BA',          4,          274)
,('BB',          5,          391)
,('CA',          4,          994)
,('CA',          5,          287)
;
create table table_B(Value varchar(2), Value2 int, Number int);
insert into table_B values
 ('AA',          1,          458)
,('AB',          2,          434)
,('AC',          3,          557)
,('CA',          4,          564)
;
select * from table_A;
select * from table_B;




Value
Value2
Number




AA
1
138


AB
2
234


AC
3
897


BA
4
274


BB
5
391


CA
4
994


CA
5
287






Value
Value2
Number




AA
1
458


AB
2
434


AC
3
557


CA
4
564



select * 
from table_A a
left join table_B b on a.value=b.value
   and a.value2=b.value2
left join table_B c on b.value is null and c.value='CA'




Value
Value2
Number
Value
Value2
Number
Value
Value2
Number




AA
1
138
AA
1
458
null
null
null


AB
2
234
AB
2
434
null
null
null


AC
3
897
AC
3
557
null
null
null


BA
4
274
null
null
null
CA
4
564


BB
5
391
null
null
null
CA
4
564


CA
4
994
CA
4
564
null
null
null


CA
5
287
null
null
null
CA
4
564



select a.value valueA
  ,coalesce(b.value,c.value) value
  ,coalesce(b.value2,c.value2) value2
  ,coalesce(a.number,c.number) numberA
  ,coalesce(b.number,c.number) numberB
from table_A a
left join table_B b on a.value=b.value
   and a.value2=b.value2
left join table_B c on b.value is null and c.value='CA'




valueA
value
value2
numberA
numberB




AA
AA
1
138
458


AB
AB
2
234
434


AC
AC
3
897
557


BA
CA
4
274
564


BB
CA
4
391
564


CA
CA
4
994
564


CA
CA
4
287
564



fiddle

There are a few different types of joins.  Inner and outer are the main types.
description of join types
A pattern I use when I don't want to include records that do not exist in the other table is to check for nulls in the primary key of the second:
    select * from A left join B on A.value = B.value and A.value2 = B.value2 
    where B.value is null and B.value2 is null


You are right, but here I need to replace the value and then join. If the value of Table A doesn't present in Table B then replace Table A value with 'CA' . Here CA is static.
